How to install databricks plugin for dbt project
I have a project where I am using dbt.
I have installed dbt core using the command 'pip install dbt-core'
I ran the command 'pip install dbt-databricks'
But when I run the dbt --version, I do not see the databricks under the plugin

Did you see this page?
https://docs.databricks.com/en/partners/prep/dbt.html

https://pypi.org/project/dbt-databricks/1.8.5/

Make sure python is installed on the system.
In my case I want to install dbt-core version 1.6.0 and I need the compatible databricks adapater to it.
This is the command that I used.
pip install dbt-core==1.6.0 dbt-databricks

then, run dbt--version and make sure it shows the dbt-core as installed and under the adapter section make sure databricks is installed
